# When I try to insert data into my posgresql database nothing happens

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I'll just start by saying that I started with python,docker etc. just few days ago and I'm kinda lost.

I've followed multiple tutorials and I was able to put this together.

I have a postgresql database on docker running on port 5432 and I have my app.py running on port 5000.
I created a simple website with form from which I want to send the inputs to the database. However when push the submit button nothing happens. Localhost just keeps loading and loading. No error in cmd, no nothing.
My database is called height_collector and I have a feedback table created with columns id, email and height.

app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@localhost:5432/height_collector'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

If anyone could please look at it and perhaps find a mistake or if you have a recommendation for good tutorial on how to connect my py app to postgress database on docker I would be really happy. Thank you for help.

Docker logs postgres:

```
D:\ZCT_zadanie>docker logs postgres
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
sh: locale: not found
2021-03-19 18:25:51.752 UTC [27] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start


WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
waiting for server to start....2021-03-19 18:25:53.304 UTC [31] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-03-19 18:25:53.348 UTC [32] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-19 18:25:52 UTC
2021-03-19 18:25:53.357 UTC [31] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
ALTER ROLE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

waiting for server to shut down....2021-03-19 18:25:53.400 UTC [31] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-03-19 18:25:53.405 UTC [31] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-03-19 18:25:53.407 UTC [31] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 38) exited with exit code 1
2021-03-19 18:25:53.407 UTC [33] LOG:  shutting down
2021-03-19 18:25:53.460 UTC [31] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2021-03-19 18:25:53.523 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-03-19 18:25:53.523 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-03-19 18:25:53.532 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-03-19 18:25:53.567 UTC [42] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-19 18:25:53 UTC
2021-03-19 18:25:53.578 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-03-19 18:26:17.065 UTC [49] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:26:18.150 UTC [50] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:26:23.219 UTC [51] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:26:43.049 UTC [52] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:26:44.144 UTC [53] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:26:49.209 UTC [54] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:26:57.697 UTC [56] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:26:58.939 UTC [57] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:27:19.041 UTC [58] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:27:25.218 UTC [59] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:27:50.702 UTC [60] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:27:55.976 UTC [62] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:27:56.288 UTC [63] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:05.209 UTC [64] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:06.297 UTC [65] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:11.363 UTC [66] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:20.625 UTC [67] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:21.316 UTC [68] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:21.514 UTC [69] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:21.685 UTC [70] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:21.826 UTC [71] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:21.998 UTC [72] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:22.194 UTC [73] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:22.382 UTC [74] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:22.556 UTC [75] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:22.868 UTC [76] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:23.051 UTC [77] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:23.244 UTC [78] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:23.460 UTC [79] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:28:53.535 UTC [80] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:29:40.472 UTC [82] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:32:22.609 UTC [86] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:32:23.702 UTC [87] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:33:58.625 UTC [90] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:33:59.873 UTC [91] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:34:04.920 UTC [92] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:35:44.469 UTC [94] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:35:45.580 UTC [95] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:36:01.821 UTC [97] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:40:08.252 UTC [102] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:40:09.357 UTC [103] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:43:34.687 UTC [107] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:43:35.351 UTC [108] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:43:35.543 UTC [109] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2021-03-19 18:43:35.722 UTC [110] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
```

Docker-compose up:

```
D:\ZCT_zadanie>docker-compose up
Starting zct_zadanie_postgres_1 ... done
Starting zct_zadanie_pgadmin_1  ... done
Attaching to zct_zadanie_postgres_1, zct_zadanie_pgadmin_1
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:28.074 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:28.075 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:28.084 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:28.139 UTC [19] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-19 19:20:22 UTC
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:28.151 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:32.106 UTC [26] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:37.205 UTC [27] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
pgadmin_1   | [2021-03-19 19:20:39 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
pgadmin_1   | [2021-03-19 19:20:39 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin_1   | [2021-03-19 19:20:39 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
pgadmin_1   | [2021-03-19 19:20:39 +0000] [82] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 82
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:20:48.130 UTC [28] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:21:17.382 UTC [29] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping zct_zadanie_pgadmin_1  ... done
Stopping zct_zadanie_postgres_1 ... done
```

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile and docker run commands?

Comment: I have not yet learned how to write Dockerfile yet..
But these are tho commands I used to set it up.

`docker network create pgnet`


`docker volume create pgdata`


`docker run  ^
    --name postgres ^
    --network pgnet ^
    -v E:\docker_volume:/data ^
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword ^
    -d postgres:10.4-alpine`

Now that I think about it, I should have Dockerfile created, shouldn't I?
Is this a good example of Dockerfile that I should follow? https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-flask-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/

Comment: You do not need a dockerfile for db.

Comment: I seems fine just wait after docker-compose up command and localhost:8080/login will be your running page after that you can follow step 3.

Comment: And only docker-compose containers should be up to be sure and clear. Not any other postgres.

Comment: I stopped and removed all containers just to be sure. Then I did docker-compose up, waited for a bit and then I tried localhost:8080 in browser. Unfortunately I did not get to pgadmin but I again got the page is not available

Comment: Change 8080 to 9090 on compose yaml and run again.

Comment: It worked on 9090! Ok so I'm in pgadmin I added new server followed your instructions.
Now I should change the URI in app.py to `'postgresql://postgres:mysecretpassword@localhost:5432/postgres'`?

And one more question, should I create table in pgadmin before I try to send something there or will app.py take care of it? Again I'm really sorry for bothering you this much and I owe you big time for your patience with me. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: create your database `height_collector` from pgadmin. And uri is `postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5446/height_collector`

Comment: Now if I need the app to run on port lets say 5000 and database at the same time I need to add the app to docker-compose.yaml, right?

Comment: No not necessary adding to compose file. you can use localhost:5000 for your app

Comment: -snip-
Nevermind I'm just stupid, sorry.

Comment: You can use docker-compose -d up and it will run without printing log. Containers need to be up if you need to connect to database.

Comment: Yeah I just kinda ralised.. Or I could have just opened another cmd.. I'm sorry.

Comment: Is it working fine?

Comment: I just finished setting up the table and it works. Again I want to tank you so so so much for your help and patience with me, you are amazing! I wish I could invite you for a beer or something at least in my life. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. I am happy that it is solved. Please accept answer and have a good coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let' s have a clear start.

1. Kill all container

   docker kill $(docker ps -q)
2. copy this command to a file which is named docker-compose.yaml
   Then run command docker-compose up (If not installed please check [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/))

---

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4-alpine
    ports:
      - "5446:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/data
    networks:
      - app-network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  postgres-data:
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

3. Add new server ->

---

```
Host: postgres
Port: 5432
db: postgres
user: postgres
pasword: postgres
```

Comment: I got this error: docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint postgres (a90ca8cded1c5fcadeaf4c3d87e3eb911145e23a0c9d33a8c1ac2d7cc9ed99da): Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated.

Should I change the first part or the second part of the port to allocate a new one?

Comment: On your pc 5432 is used for another application. You can specify another one. `-p 5433:5432` 5433 will be on your machine. Also use 5433 in your db_uri

Comment: I keep getting the same error.. I tried the 5433 port and also I tried 8001 but the same happened

Comment: It is about your local ports. Try one which is not used on your local. 5000 - 5444 - 5*** something

Comment: Should I run the pgadmin on the same port? For example run pgadmin on 5444:5432 and also postgres on 5444:5432?
Because no matter what port I try from the 5...something I keep getting the same error.


Right now I'm running it like this:

`docker run -p 5446:5432 --name pgadmin --network pgnet -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret" -d dpage/pgadmin4`

`docker run --name postgres --network pgnet -p 5446:5432 -v D:\docker_volume:/data -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres:10.4-alpine`

Comment: Pgadmin seems to work on all of them but postgres not even on one of them

Comment: Pgadmin is working on 8080 or something like that. -p 8090:8080 is enough. But for postgres you can use 5446:5432. You can not use same port for both of them.

Comment: it seems to work, I didn't get the error but now when I try to access the pgadmin on localhost in browser neither localhost:5446 or localhost:8090 seem to work for me

Comment: I'm really sorry for being this annoying but how do I check that?

Comment: Just connect from local with psql -h localhost -p 5446 -u postgres -p mysecretpassword or from pgadmin from connect db section.

Comment: When I tried the command it said: 'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. And I couldn't connect to pgadmin on localhost

Comment: logs from docker logs postgres
`2021-03-19 18:25:53.523 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-03-19 18:25:53.523 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-03-19 18:25:53.532 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-03-19 18:25:53.567 UTC [42] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-19 18:25:53 UTC
2021-03-19 18:25:53.578 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-03-19 18:26:17.065 UTC [49] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet`
the last one repeats itself like 20 times

Comment: I have edited answer. Please follow steps.

Comment: Ok, so I have created the docker-compose file and when I tried to connect to localhost:5446 on my browser I got this message in cmd: postgres_1  | 2021-03-19 19:17:31.004 UTC [59] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet

This is what I got: https://i.imgur.com/GnIbNnW.png

Comment: Not localhost 5446. pgadmin is locahost:8080. And from pgadmin host is postgres not localhost.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I now tried localhost:8080 but I just got: This site is unavailable

Comment: Can you share your logs by editing your question.